# Inverse convolution of image

Tags: image, algorithm, convolution

I have source and result image. I know, that some convolution matrix has been used on source to get result. Can this convolution matrix be computed ? Or at least not exact one, but very similar.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In principle, yes.  Just convert both images to frequency space using an [FFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) and divide the FFT of the result image by that of the source image.  Then apply the inverse FFT to get an approximation of the convolution kernel.

To see why this works, note that convolution in the spatial domain corresponds to multiplication in the frequency domain, and so deconvolution similarly corresponds to division in the frequency domain.  In ordinary deconvolution, one would divide the FFT of the convolved image by that of the kernel to recover the original image.  However, since convolution (like multiplication) is a commutative operation, the roles of the kernel and the source can be arbitrarily exchanged: convolving the source by the kernel is exactly the same as convolving the kernel by the source.

As the other answers note, however, this is unlikely to yield an exact reconstruction of your kernel, for the same reasons as ordinary deconvolution generally won't exactly reconstruct the original image: rounding and clipping will introduce noise into the process, and it's possible for the convolution to completely wipe out some frequencies (by multiplying them with zero), in which case those frequencies cannot be reconstructed.

That said, if your original kernel was of limited size (support), the reconstructed kernel should typically have a single sharp peak around the origin, approximating the original kernel, surrounded by low-level noise.  Even if you don't know the exact size of the original kernel, it shouldn't be too hard to extract this peak and discard the rest of the reconstruction.

#### Example:

Here's the [Lenna test image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) in grayscale, scaled down to 256×256 pixels and convolved with a 5×5 kernel in GIMP:

[image: Original] ∗ [image: Kernel] → [image: Result]

I'll use Python with numpy/scipy for the deconvolution:

```python
from scipy import misc
from numpy import fft

orig = misc.imread('lena256.png')
blur = misc.imread('lena256blur.png')
orig_f = fft.rfft2(orig)
blur_f = fft.rfft2(blur)

kernel_f = blur_f / orig_f         # do the deconvolution
kernel = fft.irfft2(kernel_f)      # inverse Fourier transform
kernel = fft.fftshift(kernel)      # shift origin to center of image
kernel /= kernel.max()             # normalize gray levels
misc.imsave('kernel.png', kernel)  # save reconstructed kernel
```

The resulting 256×256 image of the kernel, and a zoom of the 7×7 pixel region around its center, are shown below:

[image: Reconstructed kernel]
[image: Zoom of reconstructed kernel]

Comparing the reconstruction with the original kernel, you can see that they look pretty similar; indeed, applying a cutoff anywhere between 0.5 and 0.68 to the reconstruction will recover the original kernel.  The faint ripples surrounding the peak in the reconstruction are noise due to rounding and edge effects.

I'm not entirely sure what's causing the cross-shaped artifact that appears in the reconstruction (although I'm sure someone with more experience with these things could tell you), but off the top of my head, my guess would be that it has something to do with the image edges.  When I convolved the original image in GIMP, I told it to handle edges by extending the image (essentially copying the outermost pixels), whereas the FFT deconvolution assumes that the image edges wrap around.  This may well introduce spurious correlations along the x and y axes in the reconstruction.

Comment: Thanks.. Its not precise kernel, but result is good enough for me.

Comment: I am trying to rewrite code to C. rfft2 is FFT aka. DFT aka DCT of real input and returning real output ? And this line: kernel_f = blur_f / orig_f .. its / of each element or its matrix division (multiply by inverse) ?

Comment: I believe the output of [rfft2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft2.html) is complex, but it omits the symmetrical half of the output you'd get from applying a generic complex FFT to real input. It's not a DCT. Anyway, any FFT routine should do it. And yes, `/` on numpy arrays just does element-wise division (i.e. multiplication by inverse). I think I can provide C code with GSL later if you need it (but not now, I'm not sober enough for that at the moment).

Comment: :) C code would be good... I am using fftw and real_to_real FFT is there marked as DCT. I try to run real_to_complex FFT. Element-wise division is multiplication by inverse ? I thought, that element-wise means res[0][0] = m1[0][0] / m2[0][0] etc (but with inverse its not that simple)

Comment: It's [complex division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Multiplication_and_division), just as ordinary convolution in Fourier space needs complex multiplication. Ps. I haven't used FFTW, but I believe the plan you should be using is [fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html).

Comment: I have added answer ith your code rewritten to C/C++ using fftw. Thanks for your help

Comment: Could the cross and background noise be caused by integer division?

Comment: I don't know why we performed normalization and centering. Can anyone clarify or point me to an explaination? I know 1D signal processing well

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical problem of deconvolution. What you called a convolution matrix is usually called the "kernel". The convolution operation is often denoted with a star '*'  (not to confuse with multiplication!). Using this notation

`Result = Source * Kernel`

The answers above using the FFT are correct, but you can't really use FFT based deconvolution in the presence of noise. The right way to do it is using Richardson-Lucy deconvolution (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution)

It is quite straightforward to implement. This answer also provides a sample Matlab implementation: [Would Richardson–Lucy deconvolution work for recovering the latent kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362701/would-richardson-lucy-deconvolution-work-for-recovering-the-latent-kernel)

Answer (score 1):

Well, an estimate can be produced if an upper bound for the convolution matrix size is known. If it's N, select N*N points and attempt to solve a linear equation system against convolution coefficients, based on the data of source and destination. Given the rounding of color components, the system won't solve, but with linear programming you will be able to minimize the total offset from expected values by small alterations of those coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to perform [deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution) with source image as kernel. But results could be unpredictable - deconvolution is very unstable process due to noise, edge effects, rounding errors etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritten [@Ilmari Karonen answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16542698/1130231) to C/C++ using fftw3 for someone, who might find it handy:

Circular shift function

```
template<class ty>
void circshift(ty *out, const ty *in, int xdim, int ydim, int xshift, int yshift)
{
  for (int i =0; i < xdim; i++) 
  {
    int ii = (i + xshift) % xdim;
    for (int j = 0; j < ydim; j++) 
    {
      int jj = (j + yshift) % ydim;
      out[ii * ydim + jj] = in[i * ydim + j];
    }
  }
}
```

Now main code

```
int width = 256;
int height = 256;

int index = 0;

MyStringAnsi imageName1 = "C://ka4ag.png";    
MyStringAnsi imageName2 = "C://KyPu2.png";

double * in1 = new double[width * height];
fftw_complex * out1 = new fftw_complex[width * height]; 

double * in2 = new double[width * height];
fftw_complex * out2 = new fftw_complex[width * height]; 

MyUtils::MyImage * im1 = MyUtils::MyImage::Load(imageName1, MyUtils::MyImage::PNG);
MyUtils::MyImage * im2 = MyUtils::MyImage::Load(imageName2, MyUtils::MyImage::PNG);

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
{
    in1[i] = ((im1->Get(i).r / (255.0 * 0.5)) - 1.0);
    in2[i] = ((im2->Get(i).r / (255.0 * 0.5)) - 1.0);
}


fftw_plan dft_plan1 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(width, height, in1, out1, FFTW_ESTIMATE);    
fftw_execute(dft_plan1);
fftw_destroy_plan(dft_plan1);

fftw_plan dft_plan2 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(width, height, in2, out2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);    
fftw_execute(dft_plan2);
fftw_destroy_plan(dft_plan2);

fftw_complex * kernel = new fftw_complex[width * height];   

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
{
    std::complex<double> c1(out1[i][0], out1[i][1]);
    std::complex<double> c2(out2[i][0], out2[i][1]);

    std::complex<double> div = c2 / c1;

    kernel[i][0] = div.real();
    kernel[i][1] = div.imag();
}

double * kernelOut = new double[width * height];

fftw_plan dft_planOut = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(width, height, kernel, kernelOut, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(dft_planOut);
fftw_destroy_plan(dft_planOut);

double * kernelShift = new double[width * height];

circshift(kernelShift, kernelOut, width, height, (width/2), (height/2));

double maxKernel = kernelShift[0];
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
{
    if (maxKernel < kernelShift[i]) maxKernel = kernelShift[i]; 
}

for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
{
    kernelShift[i] /= maxKernel; 
}

uint8 * res = new uint8[width * height];
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
{                   
   res[i] = static_cast<uint8>((kernelShift[i]+ 1.0) * (255.0 * 0.5));
}

//now in res is similar result as in @Ilmari Karonen, but shifted by +128
```

Code has no memory management, so you must clean your memory !