# Python ndarray division

Tags: python, math

I have this piece of code

```
from scipy import misc
from numpy import fft

orig = misc.imread('lena256.png')
blur = misc.imread('lena256blur.png')
orig_f = fft.rfft2(orig)
blur_f = fft.rfft2(blur)

kernel_f = blur_f / orig_f         # do the deconvolution
```

From another question here on stackoverflow ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541709/inverse-convolution-of-image)). But I know nothing about python. What is this line `kernel_f = blur_f / orig_f` supposed to do ? Is it dividing element by element or its matrix division, that can be "rewritten" using matrix inverse ? I tried google that, but found nothing usefull. If someone could post me code in C that do the same (I am using alglib for mathematic, but there is no division of matrices, afaik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is elementwise division. See [NumPy for Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) in the category of ndarray operators. ndarray: `All operations (*, /, +, ** etc.) are elementwise`