# Would Richardson–Lucy deconvolution work for recovering the latent kernel?

Tags: matlab, kernel, neural-network, fft, convolution

I am aware that Richardson–Lucy deconvolution is for recovering the latent image, but suppose we have a noisy image and the original image. Can we find the kernel that caused the transformation?

Below is a MATLAB code for [Richardson-Lucy deconvolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%E2%80%93Lucy_deconvolution) and I am wondering if it is easy to modify and make it recover the **kernel** instead of the latent **image**. My thoughts are that we change the convolution options to `valid` so the output would represent the kernel, what do you think?

```
function latent_est = RL_deconvolution(observed, psf, iterations)
    % to utilise the conv2 function we must make sure the inputs are double
    observed = double(observed);
    psf      = double(psf);
    % initial estimate is arbitrary - uniform 50% grey works fine
    latent_est = 0.5*ones(size(observed));
    % create an inverse psf
    psf_hat = psf(end:-1:1,end:-1:1);
    % iterate towards ML estimate for the latent image
    for i= 1:iterations
        est_conv      = conv2(latent_est,psf,'same');
        relative_blur = observed./est_conv;
        error_est     = conv2(relative_blur,psf_hat,'same'); 
        latent_est    = latent_est.* error_est;
    end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, issamou, I'm working on a very similar problem with Matlab. Did it finally work? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @theholy, yes, I used the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150516/2d-deconvolution-using-fft-in-matlab-problems for deconvolution (or for extracting the kernel)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple problem. Convolution is commutative. Hence, you don't need to change the implementation of RL deconvolution to obtain PSF, you can simply call it as follows:

```
psf = RL_deconvolution(observed, latent_est, iterations)
```